# How similar do trademarks have to be to be infringement?

Tags: united-states, trademark, us-federal-government

I received a marketing email from Lenovo with the slogan "Different is better." This seems quite similar to Apple's "Think different," to the point that had I seen the slogan out of context, I would have thought it was Apple's; however, I'm sure Lenovo cleared it with their legal department.

How similar do two slogans have to be for trademark infringement?

Answer (score 1):

### They have to be [substantially identical or deceptively similar](https://www.baxterip.com.au/trade-mark-infringement#:%7E:text=Under%20Section%20120%20of%20the,trade%20mark%20is%20registered%20for)

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

Substantially identical is a side-by-side comparison noting the similarities and differences.

If they are not substantially identical, then the deceptively similar test is “ between, on the one hand, the impression based on recollection of one mark that a person of ordinary intelligence and memory would have and, on the other hand, the impressions that such a person would get from looking at the second mark.”

Are they substantially identical? No.

Are they deceptively similar? Maybe.